# PHP wrong character encoding

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using a PHP script to get some data from a MySQL database table.
I can see the table has the collation `utf8mb4_general_ci`

When the text is displayed on the page, I get:

```
Cust�ias
```

Instead of:

```
Custóias
```

This is what I'm trying:

```
echo '<span id="address_city">'.iconv('utf8mb4_general_ci', 'UTF-8', $row['address_city']).'</span>', "</br>";
```

And:

```
echo '<span id="address_city">'.converter($row['address_city']).'</span>', "</br>";
```

With:

```
function converter($conteudo){
    return iconv( 'utf8mb4_general_ci', 'UTF-8', $conteudo );
}
```

And also:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

Comment: Why not setting an UTF-8 header instead of ISO. And why `application/rtf` and not `text/html`

Comment: look here: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/166405/why-are-we-using-utf8mb4-general-ci-and-not-utf8mb4-unicode-ci

Comment: I've got it! I can define the charset with PDO. Thanks!